# Setting values with Vuex

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

I'm currently trying to learn Vuex.

I want so the the `number`-value increases each time you click on the element using a mutation(`changeNumber)`.

```
let state = {
  counter: 0,
  someOtherValue: 'Text'
}

let changeNumber = {
  increment(state) {
    state.counter += 1
  }
}

let store = new Vuex.Store({
  changeNumber,
  state
})

Vue.component('counter-button', {
  computed: {
    counter() {
      return this.$store.state.counter
    }
  },
  template: `<input :value="$store.state.counter" @click="$store.commit('increment')" type="button">`
})

Vue.component('some-component', {
  computed: {
    someOtherValue() {
      return this.$store.state.someOtherValue
    }
  },
  template: '<div>{{ someOtherValue }}</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  template: '<some-component></some-component>',

})
```

My code is corrected by a bot, and I get returned two errors. What's wrong with my code?

```
Err) clicking on the paragraph causes the number value to change
Err) triggering the changeNumber mutation causes the number value to change
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think you should look into the arguments to `Vuex.Store()`.

Comment: I've tried reformating the code to what I think is corrected, but this is the furthest I've come. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the mutations to the store under the key `mutations` instead of `changeNumber`. Note that in your code `changeNumber` is not the mutation, `increment` is the actual mutation.

```
let mutations = {
  increment(state) {
    state.counter += 1
  }
}

let store = new Vuex.Store({
  mutations,
  state
})
```

Comment: I added these changes, But I still got the same output as before...